# How to split two columns data in to two rows apart from using union?

Tags: oracle

I have so called requirement called splitting the data obtained in a table after performing query into two rows.

Like as below select ID1,ID2 from table, which will retrieve the data into two columns, need to obtain the same result into two rows.

Currently iam performing the UNION statement like select ID1 from table UNION select ID2 from table.

Comment: Sorry there is change in the question asked for, the requirement is have only two columns but there maybe a possibility of multiple rows existence , like ID1,ID2(columns) values([1,2];[1,3];[4,5]) (Each row i have seperated by ; and columns by ,)now  i need single column data with multiple rows like ID1(column) values([1];[2];[3];[4];[5]). please let me know if nots clear.

Comment: It's the same query; however many rows there are.